# Redirect to www subdomain with domain as wildcard

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 10 domains all pointing to a single directory. I need all of them to 301 redirect URLs without www. to having www. for example:

http://domain1.com/foo.php -301-> http://www.domain1.com/foo.php

I've achieved this fine with normal htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain1\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Ideally the domain and TLD wouldn't be defined in the htaccess - I'm trying instead to do something more like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^^www.$](.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.$1" [R=301,L]
```

ie, if `HTTP_HOST` doesn't start with www. then redirect. I believe the part I'm doing wrong with `[^^www.%]`. I thought `[^ ]` meant 'not' and `^ %` contained a string, therefor `[not[www.]]`

I've read the apache mod rewrite documentation a lot and can't seem to figure it out

My full current htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain1\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

# Don't user-friendly remap resource files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.ico$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.css$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.js$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.gif$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.png$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.jpg$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.jpeg$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.xml$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.txt$$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]

# Remap /page/filter/?query to /index.php?page=page&filter=filter&query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&filter=$2 [QSA]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `force www` rule to this:

```
# Force www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

This will force `www` to all of your domains. Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise the `!` operator used be used in this context. Thanks a lot for the quick response.